# How to print strings in column-like in java

Tags: java, string, println

Lets say i want to print 3 lines and a number next to each separated with 3 tabs and the output seems like this:

```
this is a line          3
this is a medium line           3
this is a very long line            3
```

ok all these lines are separated with the "3" number with 3 tabs.
Is there any way to make all the "3" numbers appear the one below the other like this? :

```
this is a line                  3
this is a medium line           3
this is a very long line        3
```

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/assylias/Java-Text-Table-Formatter

Comment: "Is there any way to make all the "3" numbers appear the one below the other like this?" -- yes, there are several.  You might consider using a formatter, but you can always do formatting by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you want to output a padded `String` for each column that's equal to the length of the longest possible value.  You can either do this by hand, padding out strings where necessary or use [System.out.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and pad your output with one simple command:-

```
System.out.format("%20s%5d", str, val);
```

Internally, this uses [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) so the first argument uses that syntax to decide how many characters (in this case 32 character string `%20s` and a 10 character decimal integer `%5d`) each of the following variables take up.

Comment: That will do. Ill try it this way. Thanks!